# Laravel. How to save a new value in each row of a column?

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have a table, please see `migration` below:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('group');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to increase the `column = price` of each row by a value I received from my `input form`. I am able to see the prices that I am able to retrieve and then increase, but I am struggling to figure out how to save each value as it is increased.

What I tried:

```
public function increase(Request $request){

    $products = DB::table('products')->select('price')->get();
    $percentage = $request['increase'];

    foreach ($products as $product) {
       $price = $product->price * ((100 + $percentage)/100);
       $product->price = $price;
       $product->save();
    }

}
```

But I am getting an error, `Call to undefined method stdClass::save()`

Comment: You need to find the data you want to update first. Add `$product = DB::table('products')->find($id);` to foreach and change your foreach `foreach($products->id as $id)`

Comment: You need to create an object of Product class in order to use save method?

Comment: @AnkitJindal, thank you, I do have a Product class, apologies for not adding it to my question.

Comment: @xNoJustice, thank you I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in one statement :

```
 $percentage = $request['increase'];

   DB::table('products')->update(['price'=> DB::raw("price * ((100 + {$percentage})/100)")]);
```